# Unable to figure out permissions with docker mounted volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a docker container with a mounted volume running on an Ubuntu 20 host. I'm having trouble figuring out permissions to write to the directory.

I don't know what group to set the directory to. I set the directory to `775` on my host, but I get errors that I can't write in from the docker container. When I change the directory to `777`, I see uploaded files are written as `82:82`, which I assume is the uid:guid from docker.

I know I can set the user for the mounted directory, but I'm having trouble understanding if that means the user on the host or the container. I read somewhere I should create a host user with the same uid and then add that user to the group on the directory, but this feels like a really poor method; what if the id in the container already exists on the host?

If my google-fu has failed me, can someone help me understand better permissions control on docker volumes, or if there are any patterns I should be learning/following on this?

Comment: Sounds like you have the same problem mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/zdenekdrahos/53f16cfe902ff5f820a01b79e8c76a01). Maybe try `chown 82:82`.

Comment: In normal use I'd expect to run the container as the user ID that owns the host directory, with an option like `docker run $(id -u)`.  Don't try to make the host ownership match the container ownership, or try to bake a specific host uid into a Dockerfile.  Definitely don't make anything mode 0777.